# Custom Post type content within a slider

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, customization, loop, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slider that displays slides with info from custom post type posts (Testimonials). I have a page template set up that generates divs with the post content, but what's the best way to tackle the slider element?

P.S. I'd like the slides to display in a random order too, if possible.

Here's the code for my page template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Testimonials Page
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<div class="home-page-testimonials">
    <h1>Don't just take our word for it...</h1>
 <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials' );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $thumbnailURL;
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="home-page-testimonial">
        <img class="home-page-testimonial-icon" src="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    $thumbnailURL = the_post_thumbnail_url( array(120,120) );
                                } else {
                                    $thumbnailURL = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/DefaultTestimonialIcon.png";
                                }
                                echo $thumbnailURL; ?>">
        <div class="home-page-testimonial-info">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php if ( ! empty( get_post_meta($post->ID, "_testimonialURL", true) ) ) {
                echo '<p class="home-page-testimonial-link"><a href="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "_testimonialURL", true) . '" target="_blank">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "_testimonialWebsiteName", true) . '</a></p>';
            } ?>
            <div class="home-page-testimonial-quote"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); endwhile; endif;
    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since WP loaded with jQuery by default, you might be able to modify this script http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simple-Text-Slider-Rotator-with-jQuery-CSS.html to create a testimonials sliders.

For randomizing your query, just put

```
'orderby'        => 'rand'
```

in your $args variable like this:

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'testimonials', 
'orderby'        => 'rand');
```

There are way more arguments you can learn from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Hope this would help.